# pandas replace not working for regex \([A-Z]+\:[A-Z]+\)

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

i have these kind of data in `dataframe` --> Shares of Sears Holdings `(OTC:SHLDQ)` skyrocket.
when i try to use regex  `\([A-Z]+\:[A-Z]+\)` it doesnt replace even though regex is correct for removing `(OTC:SHLDQ)`.

```py
df['text']=df['text'].replace('\([A-Z]+\:[A-Z]+\)',regex=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need empty string for replacement:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'text':['Shares of Sears Holdings (OTC:SHLDQ)',
                           'Shares of Sears Holdings (OTC:SHLDQ)']})

df['text']=df['text'].replace(r'([A-Z]+:[A-Z]+)', '',regex=True)
print (df)
                          text
0  Shares of Sears Holdings ()
1  Shares of Sears Holdings ()
```

But if want also remove space before `(` and also `)` regex is changed with `\s+` for one or more whitespaces and escaped `()` with `\`:

```
df['text']=df['text'].replace(r'(\s+\([A-Z]+:[A-Z]+\))', '',regex=True)
print (df)
                       text
0  Shares of Sears Holdings
1  Shares of Sears Holdings
```

Comment: The `r` doesn't actually matter in the first regex, it is useful if the string contains backslashes but this regex doesn't.

Comment: @tripleee - Thank you, I dont know it.